How does one balance out the bitterness from accidentally adding too much dried herbs without it tasting to much like the balancer?
I have accidentally added to much thyme or oregano to soups on several occasions (spilled usually) and on those occasions it tasted bitter to me. I thought I would just add sugar, but either it was still too bitter tasting or it started tasting sweet as soon as the bitterness was gone.  Is bitterness like saltiness where you can really only dilute it once you gone too far over?

Address "spilled usually" by using a spoon, not dumping directly from the container...

lol @Ecnerwal  that feels like an attack!  Umm.  I will but how does that change the question? Is it a matter of quantity?  In other words, why do you ask me to clarify or address how it happens?

Prevention is better than a cure so if you change your process to avoid the primary cause of the problem, you won't have to solve it. It's a comment, not an answer, because it does not answer the question as asked. But it might avoid needing to solve the problem via preventing it.

lmao @Ecnerwal.  True enough. Still feels like an attack though. Its fine. I guess I am just clumsy. I do try to prevent that of course. It usually happens because I have the habit of shaking the ingredients into a measuring spoon over the pot.

I should note that I will continue to do that. I rarely aim for "Mise en place" despite the arguments in favor. My apologies to the chefs.

Ohhhhhhhh!!!!   You were not asking me to address it - you were suggesting how I could address it!  My apologies. I misunderstood.   Well..  I do use a spoon. And I don't always do it over the pot, but I am often in a hurry. So, I do try to address it, but sometimes it happens.

When you spill, the dried herbs usually stay on top for a little bit unless it’s into a boiling liquid.   You usually have a minute or so to grab a spoon and try to remove most of it.   I personally find that they start getting a metallic more than a bitter flavor in large amounts of oregano.   I assume there’s some chemical in there that’s usually in a small enough dose that we don’t notice it.

Yeah sometimes I am able to scoop some off the top. Yeah it might be metallic??!? I'm not that confident in my ability to distinguish. Thanks @Joe I will try to pay attention to that flavor the next time I have this mishap. Hopefully, it will never happen again.
